# AS3, is there a way to attach function when use startDrag

Tags: actionscript-3

Just wondering if there is a way you can attach a function while startDrag and constantly check the position of the event target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applay mouse listener to dragged element. Somethink like code bellow.

```
draggedElement.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, checkPositionHandler)
private function checkPositionHandler(e:MouseEvent){
   // e.currentTarget.x
   // e.currentTarget.y
}
```

Comment: so basically just add another listener to the element? Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you keep adding listeners to dragged elements and try to remve that listener on stop drag.